# Concurrent Read/Close in Go, in a crossplatform way

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, race-condition, goroutine

I recently realized that I don't know how to properly `Read` and `Close` in Go concurrently. In my particular case, I need to do that with a serial port, but the problem is more generic.

If we do that without any extra effort to synchronize things, it leads to a race condition. Simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("/dev/ttyUSB0")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Start a goroutine which keeps reading from a serial port
    go reader(f)

    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("closing")
    f.Close()
    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
}

func reader(f *os.File) {
    b := make([]byte, 100)
    for {
        f.Read(b)
    }
}
```

If we save the above as `main.go`, and run `go run --race main.go`, the output will look as follows:

```
closing
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c4200143c0 by main goroutine:
  os.(*file).close()
      /usr/local/go/src/os/file_unix.go:143 +0x124
  os.(*File).Close()
      /usr/local/go/src/os/file_unix.go:132 +0x55
  main.main()
      /home/dimon/mydata/projects/go/src/dmitryfrank.com/testfiles/main.go:20 +0x13f

Previous read at 0x00c4200143c0 by goroutine 6:
  os.(*File).read()
      /usr/local/go/src/os/file_unix.go:228 +0x50
  os.(*File).Read()
      /usr/local/go/src/os/file.go:101 +0x6f
  main.reader()
      /home/dimon/mydata/projects/go/src/dmitryfrank.com/testfiles/main.go:27 +0x8b

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/dimon/mydata/projects/go/src/dmitryfrank.com/testfiles/main.go:16 +0x81
==================
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
```

Ok, but how to handle that properly? Of course, we can't just lock some mutex before calling `f.Read()`, because the mutex will end up locked basically all the time. To make it work properly, we'd need some sort of cooperation between reading and locking, like conditional variables do: the mutex gets unlocked before putting the goroutine to wait, and it's locked back when the goroutine wakes up.

I would implement something like this manually, but then I need some way to `select` things while reading. Like this: (**pseudocode**)

```
select {
case b := <-f.NextByte():
  // process the byte somehow
default:
}
```

I examined docs of the packages [os](https://golang.org/pkg/os/) and [sync](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/), and so far I don't see any way to do that.

Comment: Do you actually need to close the file? The safest method is to just leave the reading goroutine until process exit.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to use a file handle across different thread of execution or for that matter any resource. It will only make your code complex.

Comment: @JimB, I do need to close the file in order to implement reconnection: e.g. when I unplug the device whose node was `/dev/ttyUSB0`, and I don't close the file, then the file `/dev/ttyUSB0` will still be opened, and when I plug the device back, it'll become `/dev/ttyUSB1`. I need it to be `/dev/ttyUSB0` again.

Comment: @DmitryFrank: if removing the device doesn't unblock the read, how do you know the device has been removed?

Comment: @JimB, ok that's a bad example: in this particular case `Read` will return `io.EOF` indeed, but the question is more general. E.g. consider having the goroutine which reads data from the serial port and sending the received data to some channel, and the user having a "disconnect" button, which obviously should close the file, and do that without races.

Comment: @DmitryFrank: it's not just about the race in Go -- POSIX doesn't allow you to cancel a read by closing the file from another thread. The only safe solution here is to poll the file via select/epoll/etc on the file descriptor. That still leaves a tiny race within the polling timeout, but this isn't something inherent to Go in particular.

Answer (score -1):

I belive you need 2 signals:

1. main -> reader, to tell it to stop reading
2. reader -> main, to tell that reader has been terminated

of course you can select go signaling primitive (channel, waitgroup, context etc) that you prefer.

Example below, I use waitgroup and context. The reason is 
that you can spin multiple reader and only need to close the context to tell all the reader go-routine to stop.

I created multiple go routine just as 
an example that you can even coordinate multiple go routine with it.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ctx, cancelFn := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    f, err := os.Open("/dev/ttyUSB0")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        // Start a goroutine which keeps reading from a serial port
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            reader(ctx, f)
            fmt.Printf("reader %d closed\n", i)
        }(i)
    }

    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("closing")
    cancelFn() // signal all reader to stop
    wg.Wait()  // wait until all reader finished
    f.Close()
    fmt.Println("file closed")
    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
}

func reader(ctx context.Context, f *os.File) {
    b := make([]byte, 100)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
            f.Read(b)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Read without incoming data will block indefinitely. This can't interrupt a Read call.

Comment: you might be right, I'll see if i change it to ch <-f.Read(b) instead of default:

Comment: That still doesn't change anything, because the Read is evaluated first. You simply cannot interrupt a Read directly on a file on Go (for now).